# How to generate an Certificate Sigining Request (CSR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, encryption

Im member in an online forum where you can share encrypted messages.
**Now i want to communicate with this forum over their rest-interface.
In their instructions it says:**

First generate an RSA keypair with an length of 2048 bits and store the private key secure

Next generate an Certificate Sigining Request (CSR)PKCS#10 out of the privat key and send it over the rest-interface to the server

Then store the returned x509-Zertificat

Last step is to sign and encrypt messages in the S/MIME-Format with this Zertificate and send it over the rest-interface to the server

**I know that i can generate an rsa keypair with openssl, but i wonder how i schould generate an CSR with the privat key?**

Comment: This could have been found by a simple search https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+create+csr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use openssl to generate a CSR:

```
openssl req -out myCSR.csr -key myPrivateKey.key -new
```

The result will be placed in `myCSR.csr`

Comment: Do you maybe know how i can write your statement in an format like this: `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(2048)`